# jQuery for loop get only first item value

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have jQuery loop function.

Assume I have sample data function like below:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
      alert(i); 
}
```

Now I need to get only the first item value = 2 without alert another number (1,3,4).

Is it possible to do that trick?

Comment: 1. Your loop is plain JS. 2. Use an if? 3. "2" is the 3rd item

Comment: if( i == 2 ){ alert(i);  }

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a check and [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) for unwanted indices.

Then use [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) and stop iterating for left over indices.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i !== 2) continue;
    alert(i);
    break;
}
```

Comment: Hi... how about if `2` is dynamic value? So I need whatever the value just get the first value only

Comment: where do you get `1` from? please ask the whole problem.

Comment: Sorry not `1`, I mean `2`

Comment: why not omit the loop and take the value directly?

Comment: The data is need to load on the loop then I need to get only the first value.